# `np.linalg.solve` get solution matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

`np.linalg.solve` solves for x in a problem of the form Ax = b.

For my application, this is done to avoid calculating the inverse explicitly (i.e inverse(A)b = x)

I'd like to access what the effective inverse is that was used to solve this problem but looking at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) it doesn't appear to be an option... Is there a reasonable alternative approach I can follow to recover the inverse of A?

(np.linalg.inv(A) is not accurate enough for my use case)

Comment: Why do you think `numpy.linalg.solve` would be any better at calculating inverses than `numpy.linalg.inv`?

Comment: because it actually recovers a more accurate result. I get different parameters when I do it both ways. Not tremendously different but different enough to matte for what I'm doing

And I know they're more accurate because of the math theory behind what answer I should recover... Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: Also I think there's some docs that talk about it. I read it on a discussion board. I implemented GLM first and then realized that np.linalg.solve would go faster and should recover the same result. GLM and np.linalg.solve both recover the right answer but inverse doesn't

Comment: `numpy.linalg.solve` is better at *its own job* than `numpy.linalg.inv`. It is not better at `numpy.linalg.inv`'s job than `numpy.linalg.inv`.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I'll use `np.linalg.solve` when I can and then `np.linalg.inv` when I need the actual inverse. Thank you!

Comment: It's not obvious from `inv` code, but often the inverse is calculated with `solve(A, eye(...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the docs and source code, it seems NumPy is calling LAPACK's `_gesv` to compute the solution, the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/lapack-routines/lapack-linear-equation-routines/lapack-linear-equation-driver-routines/gesv.html) of which reads:

> The routine solves for X the system of linear equations A*X = B, where
> A is an n-by-n matrix, the columns of matrix B are individual
> right-hand sides, and the columns of X are the corresponding
> solutions.
>
> The LU decomposition with partial pivoting and row interchanges is
> used to factor A as A = P * L * U, where P is a permutation matrix, L is
> unit lower triangular, and U is upper triangular. The factored form of
> A is then used to solve the system of equations A * X = B.

The [NumPy implementation for `solve`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/27b98cbe0dd9d2969e9c227e7a2070aa56f41d6d/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src#L1613) doesn't return the inverted matrix back to the caller, and just frees the memory for the inverted matrix, so there's no hope there. [SciPy provides low-level access to LAPACK](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.lapack.html) so you should be able to access the result from there. You can follow the actual implementation in LAPACK's Fortran source code [dgesv.f](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/blob/v3.9.1/SRC/dgesv.f), [dgetrf.f](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/blob/v3.9.1/SRC/dgetrf.f) and [dgetrs.f](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/blob/v3.9.1/SRC/dgetrs.f). Alternatively, you could note that NumPy's `inv` still calls the same underlying code, so it might be enough for your use case... You didn't specify *why* is it that you need the approximate inverse matrix.